# Remove duplicates based on date

Tags: r, date, duplicates

```
id=c(2,3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8)
DateofCall=as.Date(c("2013-03-22", "2013-05-25", "2013-02-17", "2013-02-19", "2013-02-  21", "2013-04-22", "2013-06-22", "2013-03-28", "2013-08-22", "2013-03-18", "2012-12-28" ) )
mydata <- data.frame(id, DateofCall)
```

I want a new data frame, where only the observations for those duplicate IDs with the latest date remain, like this:

```
id=c(2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
DateofCall=as.Date(c("2013-03-22", "2013-05-25", "2013-04-22", "2013-06-22", "2013-03-   28", "2013-08-22", "2013-03-18") )
newdata <- data.frame(id, DateofCall)
```

I tried using this, but get an error message: `test=mydata[!((duplicated(mydata$id) & max(mydata$DateofCall)) ), ]` Is there an alternative to `max()` for date variables?

Any insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
aggregate(DateofCall ~ id, mydata, max)
```

will do the trick.

```
#   id DateofCall
# 1  2 2013-03-22
# 2  3 2013-05-25
# 3  4 2013-04-22
# 4  5 2013-06-22
# 5  6 2013-03-28
# 6  7 2013-08-22
# 7  8 2013-03-18
```

*Update*

This version keeps any number of additional columns:

```
subset(mydata, ave(DateofCall, id, FUN = max) == DateofCall)
```

Comment: @Sven -- Would I be able to use the aggregate command to subset the data to just include the unique Ids with the latest dates? In reality, my dataset has more than Id and DateofCall as variables.